# ClickListener and TouchListener don't work on a child view

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I have 2 custom Views: 1. BoardView 2. BallView. I add The BallView to the BoardView and the BoardView to my layout.

When I click on the BallView with ClickListener and TouchListener nothing happens. As if the BoardView overlaps the BallView area.

***Code:***

```
    board = new BoardView(this);        
    ball = new BallModel(100, 200,50,screenWidth, screenHeight);               
    ballView = new BallView(this, ball);


    ballView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            System.out.println("Hey");

            return true;
        }
    });

    ballView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Hey");

        }
    });


    board.addView(ballView);
```

**Updated:**

```
public class BoardView extends View
{
private List<View> mShapes = new ArrayList<View>();

public BoardView(Context context)
{
    super(context);     
}

public void addView(View view) 
{
    mShapes.add(view);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for(int i=0; i<mShapes.size(); i++)
    {
        View view = mShapes.get(i);
        view.draw(canvas);
    }

}       
}

public class BallView extends View
{
BallModel mBall;
Paint mBallPaint;

public BallView(Context context, BallModel ball) 
{
    super(context);
    mBall = ball;
}

private Paint getPaint()
{
    if(mBallPaint == null)
    {
        mBallPaint = new Paint();
        mBallPaint.setColor(mBall.getColor());
    }
    return mBallPaint;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = getPaint();
    paint.setColor(mBall.getColor());
    canvas.drawCircle(mBall.getX(), mBall.getY(), mBall.getRadius(), paint);    
}

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: really depends what you are overriding in your custom views.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins I added the major code, thanks.